# Can't add or remove ComboBox items

Tags: java, methods, combobox

I'm writing a program with some methods. In one of the methods I want to add some Strings to a ComboBox. This doesn't work, I can't remove or add items. But, I don't get an error either.

The method is reached well, when I print something in this method, it's in the output. Probably something is wrong with the declaration/instantiation of the combobox, but I don't know what to change. I tried `public void vulDropdowns(JComboBox Host1Dropdown){` instead of just `public void vulDropdowns(){`, but that doesn't work. Then I get an error. It's probably something really stupid but I don't see it, and I don't have much experience with Java. It's a big program if I should put all code of all classes here.  But the most important parts (I think) are:

**Class VirusGUI: The ComboBox is created by the 'design' option, so it should be right, I can't edit that part of the code. When the button is pressed, the program reads a file, and some data should go to the combobox. The method readfile.choosefile is called.**

```
public class VirusGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

VirusLogica viruslogica = new VirusLogica();

public VirusGUI() {
initComponents();
    }

private void SearchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   ReadFile readfile = new ReadFile();
   readfile.chooseFile(PathTextfield);
```

**Class ReadFile: After the while loop, I call the VulDropdown (fillDropdown) method in the VirusLogica class. The 'test' is printed, so the method is executed.**

```
public class ReadFile {
    public VirusGUI virusGUI = new VirusGUI();
    public VirusLogica virusLogica = new VirusLogica();
    JComboBox Host1Dropdown;

    while (s.hasNext()){

                String[] lineData = (String[]) s.nextLine().split("\\t", -1);
                if (!"virus tax id".equals(lineData[0]) && !"".equals(lineData[7]) && !"".equals(lineData[0]) && !"".equals(lineData[1]) && !"".equals(lineData[8]) && !"".equals(lineData[2])) {
                        virusLogica.virusChecker(lineData, classificatie); 
                        virusLogica.hostChecker();
                }
            }

            virusLogica.vulDropdowns();
            System.out.println("test");
```

**Class VirusLogica: The class with the method. 'Test 2' is printed, so the method is executed again. But the items in the combobox aren't removed. Same when I try to add something.**

```
public class VirusLogica {
     JComboBox Host1Dropdown = new JComboBox();

    public void vulDropdowns(){
        Host1Dropdown.removeAllItems();
        System.out.println("test 2");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interact with a JComboBox's list, called a model, you need to get the model first. For example:

```
JComboBox Host1Dropdown = new JComboBox();
Host1Dropdown.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"item1", "item2"});
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel)Host1Dropdown.getModel();
model.addElement("item3");
model.removeElement("item1");
model.removeAllElements();
```